# install packages with yum disabled

Tags: centos

[image: this is what is displayed when i uuse the yum command to install or do any other manipulation]

Toda, i tried to install samba with yum, but i got an error and a series of instruction which i don't understand because it's the first time i'm working in this environment; the error and instructions are listed in the screenshot

Comment: Check internet connection: `ping google.com`

Comment: unknown service or name

Comment: Set DNS and routing

Comment: @KOOHKOOHSarah You need to be able to access the internet from your VM so that `yum` can pull the package details from an online repository. You can do this by adding a NAT network adapter to your VM. Some additional configuration may be required on your guest OS (CentOS) side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. confirm you network is work. You can `ping www.google.com` or check nerwork config. For example:

   > cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
   >
   > ls -a
   >   [image]
   >
   > vi ifcfg-enp3s0 
   >   [image]

set `REBOOT` argument is `yes`. then restart the network `service network restart`.

now. you can reinstall the package.

Comment: Try running dhclient and check internet access like said in upper comments. If it works, try yum.